# Complex numbers, absolute value

Tags: complex-numbers

How can i solve this equation: $ |z+i|=|z-1| $ I have tried$z=x+iy$, $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $ z=re^{i\theta}$, comparing left and right side, nothing works. I cant come up with the correct answer. Would love some help

Comment: A much easier approach is to note you are looking for all the points equidistant from $-i$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach should work. Let $z=x+iy$ so:

$$|x+iy+i|=|x+iy-1|$$

$$\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}$$

$$x^2+y^2+2y+1=x^2-2x+1+y^2$$

$$2y=-2x$$

$$y=-x$$

So a diagonal line through the origin with slope $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by other users, we can solve this geometrically (they haven't explained how to do so).

You look for all $z$ such that $z$ is equidistant from $-i$ and $1$. As any complex $z$ can be seen as an ordered pair of reals $(\text{Re}(z),\text{Im}(z))$, you may equivalently consider the problem in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ equipped with the euclidean distance, that is:

$$d\left((x_{1},y_{1})\,,\,(x_{2},y_{2})\right)=\sqrt{(x_{1}-x_{2})^{2}+(y_{1}-y_{2}^{2})}$$

And you can see that this distance is the modulus of the complex $(x_{1}-x_{2})+(y_{1}-y_{2})\text{i}$, which is $|z-(x_{2}+y_{2}\text{i})|$ for $z=x_{1}+y_{1}\text{i}$.

You look for all points of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ equidistant from $(0,-1)$ (which represents the complex $-i$) and $(1,0)$ (which represents the complex $1$).

But the set of points in a plane equidistant from two distinct points is the perpendicular bisector of the line segment determined by these points: in this case, the perpendicular bisector is $y=-x$, wich corresponds to $\text{Re}(z)=-\text{Im}(z)$, namely the set of complex numbers $\{a-a\text{i}\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

[image: Geometric]

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution is to use the definition of the field norm as $ |z| = \sqrt{N(z)} = \sqrt{z \cdot \bar{z}} $ where $ \bar{z} $ denotes the complex conjugate of $ z $. Squaring both sides, our equation reads

$$ (z + i)(\bar{z} - i) = (z-1)(\bar{z} - 1) $$
$$ z\bar{z} - iz + i\bar{z} + 1 = z \bar{z} - z - \bar{z} + 1 $$
$$ (i+1) \bar{z} = (i-1) z $$
$$ -2\bar{z} = -2i z $$

from which it follows that we are looking at the set of points such that $ \bar{z} = iz $, so conjugation corresponds to a counterclockwise rotation of $ \pi/2 $ radians. This implies that $ \arg(z) = 3\pi/4, 7\pi/4 $ and we are looking at the line $ \Im(z) = -\Re(z) $.

Answer (score 0):

$z = x + iy$ works fine. If we plug it into the equation and simplify, we get, $x+y = 0$. So $x = -y$ or we can choose our parametric point as $(p, -p)$. We can verify it by pluging it back into the given equation.